# comma before that systems

Tags: punctuation

In this sentence why we use comma before that??

> "Eventually, this led to redistribution systems for luxuries and basic commodities, systems that were organized and controlled by Minoan rulers from their palaces"

I think that is restrictive adjective pronoun.

Comment: There is no comma before "that".  There is a comma before "systems".

Answer (score 0):

Comma is needed because it joins two (mostly) independent sentences:

> 1. Eventually, this led to redistribution systems for luxuries and basic commodities.
> 2. The systems were organized and controlled by Minoan rulers from their palaces.

Without the comma, it would be difficult for the reader / listener to decide where one sentence ends and where the other one begins, and the meaning of the entire text might get lost.